# Javascript Firebase getDownloadURL

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, url, firebase-storage

I want to display several images on my webpage via javascript using Firebase Storage.
I use:

```
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, imageIndexPathRoot)).then((url) =>{
img.setAttribute('src', url);
```

The problem is that only the last image is displayed. If I have e.g. 5 pictures in my folder, the getDownload line with the imageIndexPathRoot is correct executed for all 5 images, but only at the last image the line img.setAttribute... is executed and unly this image was displayed on the webpage.

```
    // Now we get the references of these images
   listAll(listRef).then((res) => {
     res.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
      // And finally display them
      console.log(imageRef);
      displayImage(imageRef);
     });
    }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
    console.log("Error 1");
    });

  function displayImage(imageRef) {
    const img = document.getElementById('tierFoto');
    img.src = imageRef.fullPath;
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, imageIndexPathRoot)).then((url) =>{
    img.setAttribute('src', url);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `displayImage` is called, it does:

```
const img = document.getElementById('tierFoto')
```

So it sets each image to the same HTML element, which explains why you only see the last of the images.

---

If you want to show a separate image each time you call `displayImage`, you'll need to get (or pass in) a different HTML element each time. How to do that, depends on your HTML structure.

For example, if your HTML has `img` elements with numbered IDs, you could do:

```
res.items.forEach(function(imageRef, i) { //  get index from forEacj
  displayImage(imageRef, i); //  pass it to displayImage
});
```

And then

```
function displayImage(imageRef, index) { // get index from caller
  const img = document.getElementById('tierFoto-'+index); // use index to look up element
  ...
```

Comment: Hello Frank,
thank you so much for your answer, I tried your proposal but I still have problems.

Comment: "I still have problems" That is incredibly hard to help with. What changed when you used the code from my answer? What specific problem do you have left that you are asking for further help with?

Comment: The first code segment seems to work correctly, the problem is in the displayImage funtion (at getDownloadURL). The function is called correctly with the correct parameter imageRef. At debugging I see that for the first, second... image the img.setAttribute('src', url) was not executed and also url was undefined. After some images later (not the last one) I get an "Error 1", the img.setAttribute('src', url) was executed and also url was defined (https://...) and this picture is displayed.

Comment: Maybe my problem is that several "processes" are running in parallel?

Comment: The problem in your original code was that you were setting all images to a single HTML element. To see all images, you'll need to set each to its own HTML element that either already exists (which is what the code in my answer assumes) or that you generate fro the code itself.

Comment: Thank you Frank so much. It is working now :-) Additional I had some errors in the URL generation.